# Get the initial matrix of a shuffled matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a problem. I shuffled a matrix with the siamese method and I used this code:

```
function magic = magicsquare(matrix,n)
magic=zeros(n,n);
i=1;
j=(n+1)/2;
for ki=1:n
for kj=1:n
  is=i;
  js=j;
  magic(i,j)=matrix(ki,kj);
  i=n-rem(n+1-i,n);
  j=rem(j,n)+1;
  if magic(i,j)~=0
    i=rem(is,n)+1;
    j=js;
  end
end
end
```

Now, having only the shuffled matrix, I need to get the initial matrix. How can I do that? 
Also I have to mention that my matrix only consist 0 and 1.

Update: If I have a magic square  with numbers from 1 to n (I tested for a matrix of 11x11 and 5x5) the code for getting the initial matrix is:

```
function magic = reversemagicsquare(matrix,n)
i=1;
j=(n+1)/2;
for ki=1:n
  for kj=1:n  
      is=i;
      js=j;
      magic(ki,kj)=matrix(i,j);
      i=n-rem(n+1-i,n);
      j=rem(j,n)+1;
  end
    if matrix(i,j)~=0
    i=rem(is,n)+1;
    j=js;
end
end
```

But my problem is that I have a matrix containing ones and zeros. And in this particular case the solution mentioned above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the following on line 3 and an additional function ouput:

```
function [magic,original_matrix] = magicsquare(matrix,n)
magic=zeros(n,n);
original_matrix= magic; %original matrix
i=1;
j=(n+1)/2;
for ki=1:n
for kj=1:n
  is=i;
  js=j;
  magic(i,j)=matrix(ki,kj);
  i=n-rem(n+1-i,n);
  j=rem(j,n)+1;
  if magic(i,j)~=0
    i=rem(is,n)+1;
    j=js;
  end
end
end
```

Also, just FYI, [`magic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/magic.html) is a built-in function in matlab, and if you name your variable `magic`, you'll override the function definition, so I'd suggest using a name like `magic_matrix`.

Comment: Because this function is part of an encription process. So in decription part I will only have the output of my magic function, from wich I need to get the original image